# Edit pdf file in lilbre

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, pdf, editing

I received a pdf file which was created in Adobe. Now I had to edit this pdf file. I opened it in LibreOffice. But either the page or the text was not in the correct format. The texts were exceeding the page boundary like this :
[image]

So, when I'm saving it as pdf after necessary edits, I am losing those texts outside the page.
I tried to change the format of text from Fromat > Text > adjust to contour.

Nothing happened and honestly I don't have a clue about why this is happening, what to do or how to change spacing/bullets properties or anything in Ubuntu.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The **pdftotext** may assist, in terminal do

**apt search pdftotext**

or

**apt search pdf**

For further details: 
https://github.com/EvertonCa/PDFtoText

or

https://github.com/opencats/OpenCATS_Documentation/blob/master/docs/Install-Ubuntu-16.04.rst

Self uses occasionally to extract text from PDFs am not sure about entire PDF documents.

**BTW** am NOT sure correctly extracts exactly due different code, layouts, texts in PDF documents.

.